# How do I get the parent directories of all .h files through batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Explanation: Now I got

```
C:\home\include\abc.h, 
C:\home\include\def.h 
C:\home\xyz\abc.h
```

by using

```
for /r %%F in (*.h) do set "files=!files!%%F "
```

but I need only

```
C:\home\include 
C:\home\xyz
```

which are the directories having .h files.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the folders and for each one test if it contains `*.h` files

```dos
for /d /r %%a in (*) do if exist "%%a\*.h" echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell way:

```
> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ? { Test-Path ($_.FullName + "\*.log") } 
| Select-Object FullName
```